# Configuration file .NET framework Library to .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm migrating a custom  ORM library from .NET Framework 4.5 to .NET standard 2.0. I've configured the solution to be multitarget: .NET Framework 4.5.2 and .NET Core 2.2.
The biggest change is how to manage the Configuration files in .NET Core. 
The library is made to refer always to the internal config file (that use ConfigurationManager) to retrieve all kind of configuration options, even the connectionstrings. 
Here is an example on how this config class is structured

```
public static class MyConfig
{
    public static string MyCnString
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_mycnstring))
                    _mycnstring=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycnstring"]
            return _mycnstring;
        }
    }

    public static string MySetting
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_myappsetting))
                _myappsetting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyAppSetting"];
            return _myappsetting;
        }
    }
}
```

This class is mainly used inside the library.
Now I would like to understand how to refactor this class to be .NET core compatible, and allow the library to be used in .NET Core app or Site.
I cannot figure how to use IConfiguration or IOption in a startup.cs to initilize the MYCOnfig class and then be used as a static class by the library as in .NET Framework.

Comment: You don't need (and shouldn't try) to use anything as  a static class. Configuration is *injected* either as the `IConfiguration` interface from the outside or as concrete classes. If you have to, you can retrieve the setting from the injected and stored `IConfiguration` with `GetValue`, eg `_config.GetValue("MyORM:Connection")`.

Comment: Instead of a static `MyConfig` you can create a normal `MyConfig` class and populate it from configuration values with eg `Bind` or `Get`. All these are explained in [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#bind-to-a-class) which, despite the name, is about the Configuration extension in general, not just .NET Core. The same classes and methods work in .NET Old, .Net Standard and all .NET Core application types

Comment: Just some general direction based upon experience. The purpose of using the standard class library option is so it is compatible with both full framework AND core solutions. As you have found out, core loads configs with json and full you would need to configure in your top level config file and the class library would inherit. This puts you in a weird spot if you are trying to add configuration to a class library. Refactor it instead so that the class library is agnostic to configuration and the consuming application is passing it in. Will make it more reusable and save future headache.

Comment: You can keep using XML config files in .NET Core by adding a dependency to the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager NuGet package. But I agree with other comments that using static classes for this purpose is a bad practice.

Comment: The reason for wich the configuration class is static is because the orm call the class in many circumstances. One example could be when the library want to know which query timeout to apply on a query that has been markjed as 'longexecution', or which is the time priod to check for a cleaning of the cache. These are all options that could be set by the user, and must be available to the library each time is needed. So how can I retrieve these values from the library without a specific method has been called from the application (passing an IConfiguration object)?